# I keep getting this firebase error: "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom Query object"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a food ordering platform with HTML, CSS and JS, and I'm using Firebase for the backend. The way implemented auth for the food vendors was with email and password, but I also wanted other info from each vendor, so I made a collection in Firestore named vendors and saved the data there, including the UID of the vendor after the vendor successfully signs up. My current issue is that I keep getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type `DocumentReference`, but it was: a custom Query object"

while trying to retrieve the document that contains the UID of the current signed-in user

here is the code

```js
const shopNameElement = document.querySelector('.shop_name')

  
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const uid = user.uid;
      const userQuery = query(vendorRef, where("vendor_id", "==", uid))

      getDoc(userQuery)
        .then((doc) => {
          vdata = doc.data()
          console.log(vdata)
        })


    } else {
      shopNameElement.textContent = "You are not signed in";
    }
  })
```

Basically what I tried doing here was to get the shop name from the document with the matching UID, but I removed that for understanding sake.

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are creating `vendorRef`. That's what the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
getDoc(userQuery)
```

The [`getDoc` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdoc_4569087) gets a single document, based on a `DocumentReference`. You're passing it a `Query` object, which isn't valid - as the error explains.

---

Since a query *can* have multiple results, you need to [use `getDocs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) (plural), and then handle the resulting `QuerySnapshot` that you get back:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userQuery);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  vdata = doc.data();
  console.log(vdata);
});
```